# Reset iPhone/iPad scale after user zoom-in without refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, zooming, viewport

Is it possible to reset scale after user zoom?

I have a page in which I enable zoom:

```
$('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5" />');
```

when I press on my application "back" button, I return to a page in which I want to disable zoom and reset the scale:

I add:

```
$('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.5, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, user-scalable=no" />');
```

but if the user zoomed-in, the scale is not being reset.

Is there any way to solve it without refreshing the whole page?